# Developing an application in Android's Virtual Machine Assembly Language

Tags: android, assembly, scheme

From what I've read, the standard process to build an Android application is to write the code in Java. The code then gets compiled to a virtual machine.

I've been learning '''Scheme''' and have finished reading the chapter on Compilation from '''The Strucute and Interpretation of Computer Languages''' book.

I'd like to give it a go and try to write a compiler targeting the Android Virtual Machine. In order to do so, I'd like to know which tools are available (since I think trying to generate java code would be more difficult).

From what I've reasearched online, I've found the Smali assembler. But does it exist a more official set of tools, preferably one that integrates with Visual Studio?

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: Doesn't Java code get compiled to Java byte code and then translated to Android Runtime (Dalvik) bytecode?  It seems the only tools you would need is a Scheme compiler that produces Java byte code and whatever tool Android uses to convert Java byte code.

Comment: Another option is to implement the "SICP machine" in Java, then use that as your target.